# How to allow the users if key doesn't exist in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have two dictionaries called **profile_data** and **changed_data**.

```
profile_data = {
     "degree":"Diploma in Mechanical Engineering",
     "id":"9b1a012837364cada8b15a1a84745dab",
     "location":"Melbourne-123",
     "major":"major-test",
     "start_date":"2011-01-01"
    }
changed_data = {
         "degree":"Diploma in Mechanical Engineering",
         "*field_of_study*":"fiel of stuy test-test",
         "id":"9b1a012837364cada8b15a1a84745dab",
         "location":"Melbourne-123",
         "major":"major-test",
         "start_date":"2011-01-01"
        }
```

I need to append the data if any changes happened in **profile_data** and **changes_data.**

**my code:**

```
        for old_data in profile_data[key]:
            for new_data in changed_data[key]:
                for child_key in value['key']:
                        if new_data['id'] == old_data['id'] and new_data[child_key] != old_data[child_key]:
                            result.append({
                                'field': child_key,
                                'current': old_data[child_key],
                                'changed': new_data[child_key],
                                'created_at': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                            })
```

Here in the IF condition, I am checking the id of old_data(profile_data) and new_data(changed_data) and values of new_data and old_data, If any changes happen then appending into result.

The above code is working fine **until the key exists**, In my case **field_of_study** key doesn't exist in profile_data due to that I can't able to append it.I am getting KeyError, but I  need to append if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: None of the values are lists, why are you looping over them?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a loop. Use the `update()` method to merge the changes into the profile dictionary.

```
profile_data.update(changed_data)
```